# android camera.setParameters(parameters) giving force close

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi I am trying to set camera parameters as below

```
                   Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                   List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

                    if(flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
                    {
                        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    } 
                    else if (flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
                    {
                        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    }

                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

But I am getting Force close as

```
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:249)
 java.lang.StringBuilder.deleteCharAt(StringBuilder.java:360)
 android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.flatten(Camera.java:1292)
 android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:914)
 com.example.VideoCapture.onClick(VideoCapture.java:282)
 android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
 android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: Which one is VideoCapture.java line no. 282?

Comment: camera.setParameters(parameters) this one